# Understanding the performance of column family scans in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am interested in full table scans in Cassandra. They're not a crucial part of my database design, but I do need them occasionally and want to make sure I understand the performance implications.

Let's say I have ordered keys and am using a reasonable ordered partitioner. I'm also using immutable data, if that makes a difference (the database is effectively append-only).

Now, as I understand it, inserts go into a memtable which will then get flushed every so often to an SSTable file on disk, which will contain all the memtable's rows in sorted order. The disk will accumulate a bunch of these SSTable files which then get periodically merged/compacted (preserving sortedness) into a single file.

I'm assuming that in a fairly write-heavy environment there will be several unmerged SSTable files on disk at any given time.

Now, when I perform my paginated "table scan" using [what appears to be the accepted way in Cassandra](https://github.com/zznate/hector-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/riptano/cassandra/hector/example/PaginateGetRangeSlices.java), I'm actually asking for the keys in order. This means that rather than being able to just stream out stuff in batches from the SSTables, Cassandra needs to maintain a pointer to my current location in each table, see which is the lowest by my key ordering, and then return that to me. In my understanding, this will result in a very "jumpy" disk access pattern that will generally not perform well on any medium with expensive seeks. This problem is probably exacerbated when there are multiple nodes in the cluster.

Ideal for my use case is to be able to just say that I don't care about the order I get the rows back, as long as I get them. Then Cassandra could just send me big chunks of rows using bulk reads from disk, and not worry about providing them in order.

I guess this "question" really boils down to: is my understanding of how things work as illustrated above correct? if so, is there something I can do to make scans of this sort more pleasant? My synthesis of the problem would just be that Cassandra could do with another API call to ask for N rows in any order, with some sort of indication of where I am so that my future requests can resume from there. In many ways, it's the same pattern used in the existing range call, but the key (for performance) is that I don't care about the order.